# How can I show that $D_{2n}$ follows from these relations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups, group-presentation, dihedral-groups

Suppose we have a group $A$ which is generated by generators $R$ and $F$, subject to the relation 
$$ R^n=I, F^2=I,RF= FR^{-1}.$$

It should be just the dihedral group of order $2n$, the one generated by  $n$ rotations and 1 reflection.

I am a bit confused that how I show these relation will define $A$ to have exactly $2n$ elements.

I understand that there would be $I, R,\dots, R^{n-1}$ and $F,RF,\dots, R^{n-1}F$. But how can I show these elements are distinct. For example, how can I show $R\not= R^2F$. The notes I learned just says that if they are equal then we would have $F=R^4$ and it is not possible to get this using the relations. I am a bit worried here. How do you see that these relation does not imply $F=R^4$ or more generally $F= R^{k}$ for any $k$.

I guess this should be really basic but I don't see how.

Comment: This has been asked before. There is an obvious map from $G=\langle r,s:r^n,s^2,srsr \rangle$ to the dihedral group of order $2n$. This is clearly an epimorphism. It suffices you show both groups have the same order. Now the relation $srsr$ allows to write any word in $G$ as $s^j r^i$ with $j=0,1$ and $i=0,\ldots,n-1$ so $G$ has order at most $2n$. Since the map is an epimorphism $G$ has order at least $2n$ so it has order equal to $2n$. Since this is an epimorphism of groups with equal cardinality it is an isomorphism.

Comment: Suppose $R^k = R^jF$ for some $j \neq k$. Then $F = R^{k-j \mod n} = R^i$ for some $i$. But this violates $RF = FR^{-1}$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: That looks more like an answer than a comment to me?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, Thanks! Maybe I missed something. In order to say that the obvious map is well-defined. Do you need that $r^k\not = s,k<n$?

Comment: @BrianDing No. Since the relations hold in the dihedral group, the morphism from the free group on two letters $r,s$ passes to the quotient by the normal subgroup generated by $r^n,s,rsrs$.